# How to show respected value of table in text fields and dropdown list in mvc 5?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc 5 where i created one cshtml file for view where I have one dropdown list, one text field for time, one save button and one table which show dropdown list and text field values. Dropdown list is hardcoded.  When I created its view it show data in table along edit. I also code action method for edit in controller and work properly but can not show in respected fields. Here I share controller and its cshtml file.

```
         [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PrioritySettingData()
        {
            List<PrioritySetting> prioritySettings = db.PrioritySettings.ToList();
            return View(prioritySettings);
        }

       [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PrioritySettingDataEdit(int? id) //PrioritySetting prioritySetting
        {
            List<PrioritySetting> prioritySettings = db.PrioritySettings.Where(x => x.PriorityID == 
           id).ToList();
            return View("PrioritySettingData", prioritySettings);       
        }


//cshtml file

<link href="~/Scripts/jquery.ui.slider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.css" rel="stylesheet" />



@model IEnumerable<P_CMS.Models.PrioritySetting>
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "PrioritySettingData";
    }

    <h2>PrioritySettingData</h2>

    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>

    <tr>
        <td><label> Select Priority</label></td>
        <br />
        <td>
            <select id="PriorityID" class="col-md-2">
                <option value="High">High</option>
                <option value="Low">Low</option>
                <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
                <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <br />
    <br />
    <tr>

        <td><label> Select TAT</label></td>
        <br />
        <td>
            <input id="txtexamtime" type="text" name="txtTAT" class="col-md-2" value="00:00:00" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <br />
    <br />
    <button type="button" class="button">Save Changes</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TAT)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PriorityTXT)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TAT)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PriorityTXT)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "PrioritySettingDataEdit", new { id = item.PriorityID })

            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>

    @section Scripts {
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('#txtexamtime').timepicker({
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
            stepHour: 1,
            stepMinute: 1,
            stepSecond: 1
        });
    </script>
    }
```

Comment: Why have you got `<tr> and <td> ` tags out of a `<table>` tag??

Comment: @JamesS because on same view i embed table ,dropdownlist , time field and save button that why . if i can't use i will need to create separate view .